# Moderate errors from different measurements

Tags: statistics, variance, data-analysis, mean-square-error, measurement-theory

If there are two sets of measurement results on the same object but coming from different methods, from each results we can calculate the averages and variances of them, how can I moderate two sets of results and lower the variance in general?

Quantitively speaking, if from set one we get average $\mu_1$ and variance $\sigma_1^2$, and likewise for set 2, what is the general variance $\sigma^2$?

Obviously, $σ<σ_i$ (i=1,2), and when $σ_1=σ_2$, $σ=\frac{σ_1}{\sqrt{2}}$, so I can infer that: 
$$\sigma=\frac{σ_1σ_2}{\sqrt{σ_1^2+σ_2^2}}$$
Is there any way to prove the relation? I feel that it may need to use the property of χ^2 distribution, but how to do it exactly?

Ps: By applying the equation above, it’s easy to get the situation when there are n measurements by induction method. Here’s the result:

When n=3,
$$\sigma=\frac{\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2+\sigma_2^2\sigma_3^2+\sigma_3^2\sigma_1^2}}$$

When n is arbitrary positive integer,
$$\sigma=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n \sigma_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n {\frac{\prod_{j=1}^n \sigma_j^2}{\sigma_i^2}}}}$$

Equivalently, we can rewrite the equation as:
$$\frac{1}{\sigma^2}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}$$

Update: I’ve got some reasoning by thinking of two dimensional normal distribution. Since two measurements discussed above aren’t correlated, the combined distribution of the stochastic vectors X and Y is independent 2d normal distribution, with the probability density function as:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_1\sigma_2}\exp \left(-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}-\frac{(y-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\right)$$
To make things easier, here we suppose $\mu_1=\mu_2=0$ (since it can be proved that the final result of variance is irrelevant to the average). The next step is to calculate the distribution function of $Z=(X+Y)/2$.
To do this,$\newcommand{\dx}{\; \mathrm{d}}x\newcommand{\dy}{\; \mathrm{d}}y$ 
$$F(Z)=\int_{-\infty}^Z \dx \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{y-x}{2}} f(x,y)\dy$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

This is data validation or data reconciliation.

If you have a look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304612/standard-deviation-for-a-reconciled-value), we will see that I addressed basically the same problem.